# Toad Result Sets...HOW do you disable the ability to edit a cell directly?

Tags: editor, toad

In the Result Sets section of Toad there is an ability to manually change the value of a cell by either typing or using the drop down. WHY IS THIS A DEFAULT OPTION?? And how do I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IT IS DEFAULT OPTION BECAUSE YOUR DATASET IT EDITABLE. :-)

Make sure that the "Immediate Edit" option is unchecked on Data Grids|Visual page in Toad's Options. I suspect that it is already as this is the default. Other than that if your dataset is editable then the grid is editable. That's how Toad works and has for quite some time. It's how many users modify their data.

You have a couple of options...

If you're talking about the data grid in the Editor then you must run a query that is not editable. That means do not include ROWID in your query and do not execute "edit table_name;"

If you're talking about the Schema Browser or elsewhere in the product then check the option "Use read-only queries" on the Data Grids|Data page in Options. With that checked ROWID is excluded from queries that Toad generates. All modifications to your data will need to be done using SQL or you can selectively uncheck the "Read Only" checkbox on the data tab in the Schema Browser if you want to have a read-write dataset temporarily for the selected table.